# "Тесная связь между прикладными компонентами и Spring API"

Tags: spring

Что значит "тесная связь между прикладными компонентами и Spring API", в контексте про интерфейсы `InitializingBean` и `DisposableBean`?

> Главным преимуществом использования этих интерфейсов управления
>   жизненным циклом является автоматическое определение контейнером
>   Spring компонентов, реализующих эти интерфейсы, без каких-либо внеш-
>   них настроек. А недостаток состоит в образовании тесной связи между
>   прикладными компонентами и Spring API. Именно по этой причине для
>   реализации операций инициализации и уничтожения компонентов я ре-
>   комендую использовать атрибуты init-method и destroy-method.
>   Единственное, где могут пригодиться интерфейсы управления жизненным
>   циклом, – при разработке компонентов собственного фреймворка,
>   которые будут использоваться исключительно в контейнере Spring.

Правильно ли я понимаю, что под этим подразумевается, что с использованием атрибутов `init-method` и `destroy-method` мы можем убрать *Spring* из проекта, и он будет по-прежнему работать, а с использованием интерфейсов `InitializingBean` и `DisposableBean` проект будет жёстко завязан на *Spring*? Или же это означает что-то другое?